Upper bounds for the partial product $\prod_{pq\le x}(1-\frac{2}{pq})$ over the semiprimes
There is a lot of information out there regarding bounds for the partial Euler product
$$\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
and it can be shown that
$$\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac{2}{p}\right)<\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^2=\left(\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)^2<\frac{1}{\log(x)}.$$
Similarly, we can write $$\prod_{pq<x}\left(1-\frac{2}{pq}\right)<\prod_{pq<x}\left(1-\frac{1}{pq}\right)^2=\left(\prod_{pq<x}\left(1-\frac{1}{pq}\right)\right)^2,$$
where the product is over the semiprimes no greater than $x$. I would now like to give a similarly simple estimate of this product over the semiprimes. My first attempt is to find a lower bound for the reciprocal using the geometric series expansion
$$\prod_{pq\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{pq}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{pq\le x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(pq)^k}.$$
Letting $\mathcal{P}(x)$ denote the set of integers which can be written as a product of the semiprimes $pq\le x$, we then have
$$\prod_{pq\le x}\left(1-\frac{1}{pq}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in\mathcal{P}(x)}\frac{(2\Omega(n)-1)!!}{n}$$
where the numerator is the number of ways to partition the prime decomposition into sets of two primes. This is where I am unsure how to proceed (assuming this is the best way to go). The analogous procedure for the product over the primes is worked out here. The next step listed there is to relate this sum to the harmonic series, but in the semiprime case, not every positive integer is in $\mathcal{P}(x)$. It is, however, true that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathcal{P}(x)}\frac{(2\Omega(n)-1)!!}{n}>\sum_{\substack{1\le n\le x\\\Omega(n) \text{ even}}}\frac{1}{n},$$
but I don't see an obvious bound for this sum. How do I proceed?

One way to address the classical version is as follows: we first use the fact that the number of primes up to $x$ is $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ to compute by partial summation that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p = \int_{2-}^x \frac1t d\pi(t) &\sim \int_2^x \frac1t \frac d{dt} \frac t{\log t} \,dt \\
&= \int_2^x \frac1t \biggl( \frac1{\log t} - \frac1{\log^2t} \biggr) \,dt \\
&= \biggl( \log\log t + \frac1{\log t} \biggr) \bigg|_2^x = \log\log x + O(1).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\log\prod_{p\le x} \biggl( 1-\frac1p \biggr) &=
\sum_{p\le x} \log\biggl( 1-\frac1p \biggr) \\
&= \sum_{p\le x} \biggl( -\frac1p + O\biggl( \frac1{p^2} \biggr) \biggr) = -\log\log x + O(1),
\end{align*}
and so $\prod_{p\le x} \bigl( 1-\frac1p \bigr) = \exp\bigl( -\log\log x + O(1) \bigr) \asymp 1/\log x$.
The analogous computation will work over the semiprimes $s$, using the fact that the number of semiprimes up to $x$ is $\pi_2(x) \sim x\log\log x/\log x$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{s\le x} \frac1s = \int_{2-}^x \frac1t d\pi_2(t) &\sim \int_2^x \frac1t \frac d{dt} \frac{t\log\log t}{\log t} \,dt \\
&= \biggl( \frac12(\log\log t)^2 + \frac{\log\log t}{\log t} \biggr) \bigg|_2^x = \frac12(\log\log x)^2 + O(1).
\end{align*}
The same argument then shows that
$$
\prod_{s\le x} \bigl( 1-\frac1s \bigr) \asymp \exp\biggl( -\frac12(\log\log x)^2 \biggr),
$$
which is smaller than any negative power of $\log x$ but larger than any negative power of $x$.
